# How to access the class file of a Jar of a module in main project in android

Tags: android, gradle

I have added a module for `MyProject` as

```
implementation project(path: ':LibBarCodeScanner')
```

- Now in that `LibBarCodeScanner` has a jar file
- I need to access the files of jar file from `LibBarCodeScanner` in my
  main project for `MyProject`
- those class files are not getting accessed in main project form the
  jar

How to resolve this

Comment: If you want to use jar file then copy that jar file to libs folder of your project and add as a library.This will work.

Comment: It will show duplicate class files

Answer (score 0):

Then don't add that module to project which contains jar file